# How to create a Target shortcut to link the application with the correct program- Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to add idl virtual machine to my Target location for my IDL .sav file
I am using Inno Setup,
And the following code lines

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\clas";  Filename:  "{code:GetIDLPath}"; Parameters: """{app}\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav"""; IconFilename: "{app}\clas_icon.ico"

[Code]
function GetIDLPath(dummy: string): string;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe', '', Result);
  if Result = '' then
    Result := 'idlrt.exe';
end;
```

But the Target location end up being:

```
C:\clas\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav
```

It should be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe" -vm C:/clas/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav
```

I checked the idlrt.exe location in registry and I am providing the correct path,

Does anyone know what’s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I can see something wrong with the `Parameters` parameter value. You can't get the expected result with `-vm` option followed by the `{app}/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav` path with forward slashes if you pass an expandable `"{app}\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav"` constant. This might be better a  bit:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Icons]
; because of use of the "useapppaths" flag, there's no need to have the
; GetIDLPath function anymore; that flag do its work for you
Name: "{group}\clas"; Filename: "idlrt.exe"; Parameters: "{code:GetIDLParams}"; IconFilename: "{app}\clas_icon.ico"; Flags: useapppaths

[Code]
function GetIDLParams(Value: string): string;
begin
  // prepare the -vm option followed by a quoted application path to a file
  Result := '-vm ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav'));
  // and replace backslashes to forward slashes
  StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', False);
end;
```

Comment: Ok that only works when I change:
Name: "{group}\clas"; Filename: "{code:GetIDLPath}"; Parameters: "{code:GetIDLParams}"; IconFilename: "{app}\clas_icon.ico"

With

Name: "{commondesktop}\clas"; Filename: "{code:GetIDLPath}"; Parameters: "{code:GetIDLParams}"; IconFilename: "{app}\clas_icon.ico"

The problem is,
It creates two icons,
One outside the group,
But it has the correct line I want:
"C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86_64\idlrt.exe" -vm C:/clas/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav
Great piece of code, thanks,

Comment: The other one is inside the group, or has the group name,
But only shows:
C:/clas/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav

I guess I don’t know how to add both statements together, that is 
"{commondesktop}\clas";  AND "{group}\clas";

Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit lost. Where do you want to create that shortcut then ? And, you can also remove the `GetIDLPath` if you use the [`useapppaths`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm#useapppaths). See the update...

Comment: Well i changed your updates, but still the target is: C:\clas\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have ? Are you sure you're looking at the right shortcut (in the right program group) ? If I remember that right, they should always be overwritten, so there should be no problem that the shortcut already exists. And that post update was just an optimization (what you did with the `GetIDLPath` scripted constant function does the `useapppaths` flag for you, so I just removed that function for simplicity). I've tested this script on Windows 7 with the most recent Inno Setup and it worked. I got the expected target...

Comment: Ok i actually got it to work, but the problem is its picking the 64bit version of IDL, and i need the 64bit version. Both version are called idlrt.exe, but in different folders. Do you know how to specify which version to call?

Comment: Oh and im using windows 8

Comment: Ok, so you want to get path to the `idlrt.exe` always from a 32-bit registry view (that should contain path to a 32-bit version of it) ? If so, then we will need that `GetIDLPath` function back. There you can explicitly specify that you want to read from `HKLM32` root key.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the 32 to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Comment: Use either `HKLM32` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32`.

Comment: I tried both and they still give me the 64bit path. Here is an one of the lines i used: RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe', '', Result);

Comment: The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32` root key equal to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` one if you are running the setup in 32-bit mode. If you are running the setup in 64-bit mode, then `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` reads from 64-bit registry view and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32` from 32-bit. From this I don't get, why the explicit use of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32` root key would read from a 64-bit registry view.

Comment: I dont know: so the result is C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86_64\idlrt.exe; But i need the 32 bit path: C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe. I am clueless too.

Comment: I can close this an solved and submit the knew problem as a question.

Comment: Ok, just make sure that the key value in the 32-bit registry view under the `Wow6432Node` node in your registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe` is really the path to a 32-bit version. If that is so, then it sounds like a potential bug.

Comment: Well i can only see the 64bit path!, so your saying its not the correct path, I need to do some research and see how to find the 32bit location.

Comment: Well im not using Wow6432Node!, but i might have lost you there

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misled you. I meant that if you use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32` root key with a path starting with `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\..` in Inno Setup, the key value will be on 64-bit Windows actually read from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\..` node (that's the path you can see in `Regedit`) regardless if you run the setup in 32-bit or 64-bit mode. Do not specify the `Wow6432Node` node explicitly in your path; that's what the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32` root key does for you.

Comment: ah ok, So do you know how i should pursue this, so i can fix it?

Comment: With my previous comment I meant to check with the `Regedit` that in your 32-bit registry view (the one under the `Wow6432Node` node), so this  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe` key, is the path to the 32-bit application. My guess is that there's the same path as in 64-bit view (the one containing `..\bin.x86_64\..`). If not, then there's a problem with reading registry views (what I'm not betting on).

Comment: Well i did check:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe, and it only has a path for the 64bit version.

Comment: Ok, so then you can't read that value from this registry key. Maybe Windows wants to use that version of the application also with 32-bit use. I don't know.

Comment: Its ok, i appreciate your time and help,